# Creating multiple page application using react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created SPA using react and hence my address bar does not change when I move to another view.Kindly help in changing the address bar. News feed Code is

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Stories from './Stories';
export default class NewsFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { feed: [], showPopUp: false, showStoryPopUp: false, readArr: [], importantArr: [], counterArr: [], deleteArr: [] };
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleCreateFeed = this.handleCreateFeed.bind(this);
        this.handlePost = this.handlePost.bind(this);
        this.handleCreateStories = this.handleCreateStories.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        let self = this;
        axios.get('src/rest/feed.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                let counterArr = self.state.counterArr;
                let readArr = self.state.readArr;
                let deleteArr = self.state.deleteArr;
                for (let item of response.data) {
                    counterArr.push(0);
                    readArr.push(false);
                    deleteArr.push(false);
                }
                self.setState({ feed: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    changeImportant(index) {
        let arr = this.state.importantArr;
        arr[parseInt(index)] = !arr[parseInt(index)];
        this.setState({ importantArr: arr });
    }
    changeReadFlag(index) {
        let arr = this.state.readArr;
        arr[parseInt(index)] = !arr[parseInt(index)];
        this.setState({ readArr: arr });
    }
    decrement(index) {
        let arr = this.state.counterArr;
        arr[parseInt(index)] = arr[parseInt(index)] - 1;
        this.setState({ counterArr: arr });
    }
    handleDelete(index) {
        let arr = this.state.deleteArr;
        arr[parseInt(index)] = !arr[parseInt(index)];
        this.setState({ deleteArr: arr });
    }
    increment(index) {
        let arr = this.state.counterArr;
        arr[parseInt(index)] = arr[parseInt(index)] + 1;
        this.setState({ counterArr: arr });
    }
    handlePost(header, description,broker) {
        // console.log(document.querySelector("#title-input").value,document.querySelector("#description-input").value)
        let tempObj = { imgsrc: "images1.jpg" };
        // tempObj.header = document.querySelector("#title-input").value;
        // tempObj.description = document.querySelector("#description-input").value;
        tempObj.header = header;
        tempObj.description = description;
        tempObj.broker = broker;
        let tempArr = this.state.feed;
        tempArr.push(tempObj);
        let counterArr = this.state.counterArr.push(0);
        this.setState({ showStoryPopUp: false });
    }
    handleClose() {
        this.setState({ showPopUp: false, showStoryPopUp: false })
    }
    handleCreateFeed() {
        this.setState({ showPopUp: true });
    }
    handleCreateStories() {
        this.setState({ showStoryPopUp: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="email-class lis-cls">
                {this.state.showStoryPopUp ? <Stories handlePost={this.handlePost} handleClose={this.handleClose} /> : null}
                {this.props.userType === 'admin' ? <button id="story-btn" type="button" className="btn btn-primary fixed-cls fa fa-pencil" style={{ display: this.state.showPopUp || this.state.showStoryPopUp ? 'none' : 'inline-block' }} onClick={this.handleCreateStories} > &nbsp;Create Stories</button> : null}

                {this.state.feed.map((feed, index) => {
                    return (<div key={index} id={index} className={this.state.showPopUp || this.state.showStoryPopUp ? 'row row-feed hide-cls' : this.state.deleteArr[index] ? 'row row-feed hide-cls' : 'row row-feed'} >
                        <h4 className="list-header">{feed.header}</h4>
                        <img src={"src/img/" + feed.imgsrc} alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100" />
                        <span className="feed-text">{feed.description}</span>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-1">
                                <span className={this.state.readArr[index] ? "fa fa-check-circle pull-right" : ""}></span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-1">
                                <div className="pull-right">
                                    <div className="fa fa-arrow-up display-block-cls" onClick={this.increment.bind(this, index)}></div>
                                    <div className={this.state.counterArr[index] == 0 ? "vote-cls" : this.state.counterArr[index] > 0 ? "vote-cls upvote" : "vote-cls downvote"}>
                                        {this.state.counterArr[index]}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="fa fa-arrow-down display-block-cls" onClick={this.decrement.bind(this, index)}> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-8">
                                <button id="read" className="btn btn-success fa fa-pencil" onClick={this.changeReadFlag.bind(this, index)}>&nbsp;Read </button>
                                <button id="delete" className="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash-o" onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, index)}>&nbsp;Delete </button>
                                <button className="btn btn-primary fa fa-exclamation" onClick={this.changeImportant.bind(this, index)}>&nbsp;Important </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr className={this.state.importantArr[index] ? 'imp-cls' : 'hr-cls'} />
                    </div>)
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

stoies code is

```
import React from 'react';



export default class Stories extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handlePost = this.handlePost.bind(this);

    }
    handleClose() {
        this.props.handleClose();
    }
    handlePost(){
        let header = document.querySelector("#title-input").value;
        let description = document.querySelector("#description-story-input").value;
        let broker = document.querySelector("#broker-input").value;
        this.props.handlePost(header,description,broker);
    }


    render() {
        return (<div className={'popup-cls add-story-top'}>
            <div className={'add-story email-class'}>
                <img onClick={this.handleClose} className="cross-cls" src="src/img/cross.png" alt="Smiley face" height="35" width="35" />
                <h4 className="list-header">Create Stories</h4>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Title
                                </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="title-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Description </td>
                            <td> <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="description-story-input"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Broker </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="broker-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Ticker </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="ticker-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Category </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="category-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Direction </td>
                            <td> <input type="number" min="-2" max="2" defaultValue="0" id="direction-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Rating </td>
                            <td> <input type="number" min="-5" max="5" defaultValue="0" id="rating-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Score </td>
                            <td> <input type="number" min="-4" max="4" defaultValue="0" id="score-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Trade Price </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="trade-price-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Pre Trade Price </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="pre-trade-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Attachment </td>
                            <td> <input type="file" id="attachment-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Links </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="links-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Percentage Change </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="percentage-change-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Tags </td>
                            <td> <input type="text" id="tag-input" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button onClick={this.handlePost}  id="post-btn" type="button" className="btn btn-primary fa fa-envelope" >&nbsp;Post</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }

}
```

login code is 
    import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { login: false, userName: '', password: '' ,isValid : true};
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeUserName = this.handleChangeUserName.bind(this);
        this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit() {
        let self = this;

        axios.get('src/rest/login.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                response.data.map((user)=>{
                    if(user.userName === self.state.userName && user.password === self.state.password ){
                        self.props.setLogin( true,user.role);
                        self.setState({isValid :true })
                    }else{
                        self.setState({isValid :false })
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    handleChangeUserName(event){
        this.setState({userName : event.target.value});
    }
     handleChangePassword(event){
        this.setState({password : event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="email-class email-class-div login-cls">
                <div className="row row-login header-class">
                    <h3 className="float-class" >Login</h3>
                    <img src="src/img/star.png" className="float-class img-class" alt="Smiley face" height="35" width="35" />
                </div>
                <div className="error-div" style={{display : !this.state.isValid?'block':'none'}}>Invalid username or password</div>
                <div className="row row-login androidTextbox">
                    <input className="col-md-6" type="text" placeholder="User ID/Email" onChange={this.handleChangeUserName}/>
                </div>
                <div className="row row-login androidTextbox">
                    <input className="col-md-6" type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleChangePassword} />
                </div>
                <div className="row row-login submit-row" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div id="button" >SUBMIT</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

All three have same address.

Comment: Can you show your `Routes` ?

Comment: I do not have routes

Comment: then please show how you are navigating ?

Comment: I had made this SPA, I am not navigating, clicking on a button opens a view or rather popup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are navigating without routes unless you are showing/hiding components.  You could look into implementing the [hash router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md)